# How can I make the number that I get from the frontend to be read as a decimal

Tags: javascript

For example if a user write 12, then when its passed to the backend to be passed as 12.00.

```
var contract_hrs = document.getElementById("eng_contract_hours");
```

Comment: Thanks I didnt notice that

Comment: This is JavaScript but i made a mistake when I was adding a tag

Comment: Please provide the code where you're sending the said number to the back-end.

Comment: Where are you getting the value and where are you sending it to the backend?  How is the backend receiving and interpreting the value?  Are you just asking how to parse a string to a number in JavaScript?

Answer (score 0):

you can use .toFixed(number to get value) at the time you are getting the number in backend

```
//in backend

let num = 12;
let n = num.toFixed(2); //12.00
```

Answer (score -2):

Basically you cant, interaction between the two is based upon sending strings or binary. But what you can do is to create an enum for that. It will look kinda like this.

```
var contract_hrs = document.getElementById("eng_contract_hours");
var input_enum = {hrs: contract_hrs.value, type: int}
```

You can pass it to your backend and consume it the way you want based on the type property.

And in JS already 12 as a number is 12.00.

Comment: Basically you can. Also why describe an object as enum in JS? Also if you want to pass int as a string it should be placed inside quotation marks. Lastly, JS normally uses camelcase instead snake case.  (You are also not consistent with the use of ; to end your line)